# A trapezoid and a parallel line to its bases

Tags: geometry

The extensions of the legs $AD$ and $BC$ of a trapezoid $ABCD$ $(AB\parallel CD)$ intersect at $O$. The line $a$ passes through $O$ and is parallel to the bases of $ABCD$ and $a\cap BD=M, a\cap AC=N$. If $AB=7$ and $CD=3$, then what is the length of $MN$?
[image]

I tried to use the similarity $$\triangle ABP\sim\triangle CDP\sim \triangle NMP$$ This gives us $$\dfrac{7}{3}=\dfrac{BP}{DP}=\dfrac{AP}{CP}\\\dfrac{7}{MN}=\dfrac{BP}{MP}=\dfrac{AP}{PN}\\\dfrac{3}{MN}=\dfrac{DP}{MP}=\dfrac{CP}{PN}$$ I don't think this is very useful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: $\triangle CON \sim \triangle CBA$ and $\triangle DOM \sim \triangle DAB$

Comment: Seems like a good start. Somehow you will need to make use of point $O$ too, since without that restriction $MN$ could be any parallel line. There are at least five more pairs of similar triangles using just the points in the diagram (but you shouldn't need to use all five of them).

Comment: From the lengths $AB$ and $CD$, find the ratio of distances between parallel lines $AB$, $CD$ and $MN$, e.g. find $AD:DO$.

Comment: @MathLover, thank you for the response! So we have $$\dfrac{DO}{AD}=\dfrac{OM}{7}=\dfrac{DM}{BD}$$ and $$\dfrac{CO}{BC}=\dfrac{NO}{7}=\dfrac{CN}{AC}.$$ I don't see how this helps.

Comment: @Medi you know $CO/BC$, right?

Comment: same way, you know $DO/AD$

Comment: @Medi, please, could you read my answer ? What do you think about it ?

Comment: Hint: use the ratio of distances from $P$ to the two bases, and the ratio of distances from $O$ to the two bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\;\triangle OAB\sim\triangle ODC\;,\;$ we get that

$OA:OD=7:3$

and, by applying the dividendo property, we obtain that

$(OA-OD):OD=(7-3):3$

that is

$AD:OD=4:3\;.\qquad\color{blue}{(*)}$

From $\;\triangle ABD\sim\triangle OMD\;,\;$ we get that

$AD:OD=7:MO\;.\qquad\color{blue}{(**)}$

From $\;(*)\;$ and $\;(**)\;,\;$ it follows that

$4:3=7:MO$

hence ,

$MO=\dfrac{21}4\;.$

Analogously we can prove that

$ON=\dfrac{21}4\;.$

Therefore

$MN=\dfrac{21}2\;.$

**Addendum:**

Now we will prove that $\;ON=\dfrac{21}4\;.$

From $\;\triangle OAB\sim\triangle ODC\;,\;$ we get that

$OB:OC=7:3$

and, by applying the dividendo property, we obtain that

$(OB-OC):OC=(7-3):3$

that is

$BC:OC=4:3\;.\qquad\color{blue}{(***)}$

From $\;\triangle ABC\sim\triangle NOC\;,\;$ we get that

$BC:OC=7:ON\;.\qquad\color{blue}{(****)}$

From $\;(***)\;$ and $\;(****)\;,\;$ it follows that

$4:3=7:ON$

hence ,

$ON=\dfrac{21}4\;.$